# ReferenceError: updateSliderMargin is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel like this should be a simple fix but I'm pretty stumped on trying to get this error to stop occurring

```js
function headerShrink() {
    $(document).on("scroll", function() {
      if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
         $("header").addClass("shrink");
         updateSliderMargin();
      } else {
         $("header").removeClass("shrink");
         updateSliderMargin();
      }
    });
  }
  headerShrink();
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 60px 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  /* animation magic */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-indent: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 180px auto;
}

.shrink {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
  line-height: 24px;
}

strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <h1>baopals</h1>
</header>
  
<section class="container">
<p>
Sed nulla cred Banksy jean shorts. Reprehenderit mumblecore incididunt anim accusamus. Keffiyeh Cosby sweater in cornhole elit, tote bag cillum banjo. Shabby chic YOLO banh mi sunt. Artisan blog Neutra, polaroid adipisicing Banksy +1 lo-fi umami distillery fixie seitan. Semiotics artisan flannel mollit craft beer Blue Bottle. Bespoke biodiesel banh mi literally.
</p>

<p>
YOLO Marfa drinking vinegar polaroid laborum veniam, est disrupt umami wayfarers try-hard before they sold out fap. Culpa bitters kitsch adipisicing, nesciunt brunch squid minim post-ironic assumenda irony. Qui bespoke organic, photo booth authentic PBR velit before they sold out fingerstache nostrud flannel. Leggings chillwave est sustainable, tofu raw denim sint 8-bit keffiyeh High Life. Nostrud Austin put a bird on it, typewriter Godard gastropub ennui mlkshk deserunt assumenda. Blog letterpress meggings, nihil Shoreditch Etsy try-hard vinyl Echo Park cray farm-to-table McSweeney's High Life. Qui stumptown ex Cosby sweater street art ethnic irure dolore.
</p>

<p>
In post-ironic umami, sint +1 gluten-free pickled disrupt vinyl jean shorts velit placeat est American Apparel. Flannel cupidatat deserunt master cleanse cornhole vinyl, Banksy 8-bit fugiat pariatur. Schlitz Intelligentsia incididunt ugh, literally minim skateboard ennui. Labore deep v placeat, mlkshk biodiesel church-key post-ironic Cosby sweater twee nesciunt Blue Bottle. Salvia vero esse, exercitation cliche chambray aliquip gluten-free yr post-ironic pug narwhal kale chips ennui hella. Consequat bitters salvia delectus esse. Fap kogi forage culpa Tumblr, accusamus PBR Thundercats PBR&B banjo ullamco 8-bit bitters minim you probably haven't heard of them.
</p> 
  
<p>
Sed nulla cred Banksy jean shorts. Reprehenderit mumblecore incididunt anim accusamus. Keffiyeh Cosby sweater in cornhole elit, tote bag cillum banjo. Shabby chic YOLO banh mi sunt. Artisan blog Neutra, polaroid adipisicing Banksy +1 lo-fi umami distillery fixie seitan. Semiotics artisan flannel mollit craft beer Blue Bottle. Bespoke biodiesel banh mi literally.
</p>

<p>
YOLO Marfa drinking vinegar polaroid laborum veniam, est disrupt umami wayfarers try-hard before they sold out fap. Culpa bitters kitsch adipisicing, nesciunt brunch squid minim post-ironic assumenda irony. Qui bespoke organic, photo booth authentic PBR velit before they sold out fingerstache nostrud flannel. Leggings chillwave est sustainable, tofu raw denim sint 8-bit keffiyeh High Life. Nostrud Austin put a bird on it, typewriter Godard gastropub ennui mlkshk deserunt assumenda. Blog letterpress meggings, nihil Shoreditch Etsy try-hard vinyl Echo Park cray farm-to-table McSweeney's High Life. Qui stumptown ex Cosby sweater street art ethnic irure dolore.
</p>

<p>
In post-ironic umami, sint +1 gluten-free pickled disrupt vinyl jean shorts velit placeat est American Apparel. Flannel cupidatat deserunt master cleanse cornhole vinyl, Banksy 8-bit fugiat pariatur. Schlitz Intelligentsia incididunt ugh, literally minim skateboard ennui. Labore deep v placeat, mlkshk biodiesel church-key post-ironic Cosby sweater twee nesciunt Blue Bottle. Salvia vero esse, exercitation cliche chambray aliquip gluten-free yr post-ironic pug narwhal kale chips ennui hella. Consequat bitters salvia delectus esse. Fap kogi forage culpa Tumblr, accusamus PBR Thundercats PBR&B banjo ullamco 8-bit bitters minim you probably haven't heard of them.
</p>
  <p>
YOLO Marfa drinking vinegar polaroid laborum veniam, est disrupt umami wayfarers try-hard before they sold out fap. Culpa bitters kitsch adipisicing, nesciunt brunch squid minim post-ironic assumenda irony. Qui bespoke organic, photo booth authentic PBR velit before they sold out fingerstache nostrud flannel. Leggings chillwave est sustainable, tofu raw denim sint 8-bit keffiyeh High Life. Nostrud Austin put a bird on it, typewriter Godard gastropub ennui mlkshk deserunt assumenda. Blog letterpress meggings, nihil Shoreditch Etsy try-hard vinyl Echo Park cray farm-to-table McSweeney's High Life. Qui stumptown ex Cosby sweater street art ethnic irure dolore.
</p>

<p>
In post-ironic umami, sint +1 gluten-free pickled disrupt vinyl jean shorts velit placeat est American Apparel. Flannel cupidatat deserunt master cleanse cornhole vinyl, Banksy 8-bit fugiat pariatur. Schlitz Intelligentsia incididunt ugh, literally minim skateboard ennui. Labore deep v placeat, mlkshk biodiesel church-key post-ironic Cosby sweater twee nesciunt Blue Bottle. Salvia vero esse, exercitation cliche chambray aliquip gluten-free yr post-ironic pug narwhal kale chips ennui hella. Consequat bitters salvia delectus esse. Fap kogi forage culpa Tumblr, accusamus PBR Thundercats PBR&B banjo ullamco 8-bit bitters minim you probably haven't heard of them.
</p>
</section>
```

Here is the code in question

```
  function headerShrink() {
    $(document).on("scroll", function() {
      if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
         $("header").addClass("shrink");
         updateSliderMargin();
      } else {
         $("header").removeClass("shrink");
         updateSliderMargin();
      }
    });
  }
  headerShrink();
```

All it is doing is applying the shrink class to my header code on scroll which works fine. However when i look at the console ill have an error `ReferenceError: updateSliderMargin is not defined` for every time the scroll is called.

What is causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `on`, the [context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) of the function changes. Within the context of the `on` function, there is no defined function called `updateSliderMargin`. To fix this, [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the outer context to the function:

```
headerShrink() {
  $(document).on("scroll", function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
       $("header").addClass("shrink");
       updateSliderMargin();
    } else {
       $("header").removeClass("shrink");
       updateSliderMargin();
    }
  }.bind(this));
}
headerShrink();
```